# hid api building error in XCode

Tags: xcode, api, hid, building

I'm trying to test [this hid api](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi) for MAC in XCode by creating a project type "Core Foundation" just by importing the "hidapi/hidapi.h" library and replacing the "mac/main.c" files into the project. After adding the IOKit framework, and trying to build I got an error saying:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_main", referenced from:
>         start in crt1.10.6.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

and

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_main", referenced from:
>         start in crt1.10.6.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've looked into this error here and on the internet, but it seems that this error it's not related to specific problem, it occurs depending on the situation. Can you give me a help?

Thank you very much.